# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property - Vanilla Javascript Mouse Position

Tags: javascript

My expected result is for the image to move within the container according to the calculations made on the x-axis mouse position. That is why `Xratio` ranges from -1 to 1.

I am not sure what is the readonly property here?
I used `console.log(typeof Xratio)` and got "number".

I also used `console.log(typeof easeOutExpo)` and saw "function".

Could this be a simple mistake I am not understanding with assigning?

```js
const bxImg = document.querySelector('.bx-pic');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const xRatio = (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    console.log(typeof xRatio);

    const xRatioEased = 0;
    if (xRatio >= 0) {
        xRatioEased = easeOutExpo(xRatio);
    } else {
        xRatioEased = easeOutExpo(-xRatio * -1)
    }

    bxImg.style.transform = `scale(1.2) translate3D(${-xRatioEased * 10}px, ${0}, ${0})`;
})

function easeOutExpo(n) {
    if (n === 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 1 - Math.pow(2, -10 * n);
    }
}

console.log(typeof easeOutExpo);
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #FDFDFD;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.bx-wp {
    position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    outline: 30px solid royalblue;
}

.bx {
    position: relative;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bx-wp">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1641113994135-a9f230b1f9b0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2670&q=80" alt="A Mountain" class="bx bx-pic">
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you made `xRatioEased` a `const`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared `xRatioEased` as a `const`, so it can only be set on initialisation. Replace `const xRatioEased` with `let xRatioEased` and it should all work.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.

Comment: You're very welcome - but in future please consider upvoting answers and marking them as solutions as a token of your thanks ;)

Comment: I will, the system is telling me to wait 8 minutes before marking it as a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

`xRatioEased` is a constant. Constants can be changed **only on initialization**.  If you declare `xRatioEased` as a variable (with `let` or `var`), you can fix the issue.

If you want to know more about constants and when to use them, you can head over to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)